# Create a horizontal listview in winJs?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I have implemented a ListView and it seems vertical in orientation.

Cannot change the orientation to horizontal. I know it is easy in WinRT and Xaml but I have no idea in WinJS. Any property or method I need to set ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There's no template edition like in xaml c# for list view . I guess the only way is to use a Grid layout and change the height as to hold only one element at a time . As a result it will get on expanding to the right with a fixed height.

```
<div id="basicListView" 
    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
    data-win-options="{ itemDataSource : DataExample.itemList.dataSource, 
        itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate'), 
        layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}">
</div>
```

Specify your own height and width in cssto hold one item only

Answer (score 0):

It appears that at there are many properties supported at 8.1 that aren't supported at 8.

[GridLayout Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn255116.aspx) being one of those.

Minimum supported client : Windows 8.1 Preview [Windows Store apps only]

Easiest means that I've come across is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768503/winjs-ui-listview-horizontal):